# Не отображаются данные в ListView после обновления

Tags: android, listview, adapter

есть List, который изначально пустой, после того как нажимаем кнопку добавить, открывается AlertDialog, с полями для ввода, данные вводятся, и после ввода должны появиться в ListView.

Comment: Как у тебя в адаптере присваивается ArrayList<DataModel>?

Comment: @artemiygreg обновил вопрос. посмотри

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ОБъявите ваш список глобально и инициализируйте

```
 ArrayList<DataModel> maps = new ArrayList();
```

Ну и добавьте в список:

```
builder.setPositiveButton("Добавить", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            maps.add(dataModel);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Comment: для чего тогда loadData() если теперь он не возвращает значение? 
DataModel dataModel тоже тогда надо сделать глобальной?

Comment: все равно не помогло, данные не отображаются. тогда элемент списка добавлися и все. и изначально до ввода данных  пустой элемент списка стоит

Comment: а, да, в адаптер maps передавайте вот так adapter = new ListTovarAdapter(getActivity(), maps);

Comment: обновил ответ, проверьте.

Comment: переделал, но получается, что теперь данные не заполняются в maps, и он всегда пустой

Comment: Так у вас там был один только объект, добавьте его в другом месте

Comment: обновил, но теперь снова старая проблема, изначально появляется пустой элемент списка, а при добавлении просто добавляется элемент списка, но само оно пустое

Comment: Для чего нужно это edit_name_tovar.addTextChangedListener? Под дебагом посмотрите, при клике на кнопку, в список вы пустой добавляете объект или нет?

Comment: edit_name_tovar.addTextChangedListener на editText повесил слушатель TextWatcher , как только ввод заканчивается, то данные сохраняются, продебажил, данные с editText сохраняются

Comment: покажите тогда разметку элемента и код адаптера чтоли

Comment: сейчас еще раз продебажил,         maps.add(dataModel); вот тут dataModel =null и данные не добавляются в список, хотя в editText забираются

Answer (score 0):

Вот так должно работать

```
private ArrayList<DataModel> maps;

ImageButton add_tovar = (ImageButton)getActivity().getParent().findViewById(R.id.add_tovar);
add_tovar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
add_tovar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        inputDialog();
    }
});

adapter = new ListTovarAdapter(getActivity(), loadData());
listTovar.setAdapter(adapter);

public ArrayList<DataModel> loadData() {
    maps = new ArrayList<>();
    DataModel dataModel = new DataModel(dataModelList.getName_tovar(),dataModelList.getMark_tovar(),dataModelList.getCost_tovar());
    maps.add(dataModel);
    return maps;
}

builder.setPositiveButton("Добавить", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        adapter.addModel(dataModel);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
}
```

в адаптере

```
public void addModel(DataModel dataModel){
    dataModelsTovar.add(dataModel);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: нет, не работает, все равно отображаются пустые элементы списка

Comment: если элементы отображаются но пустые, тогда у тебя где то нарушена логика в другом месте. Можешь попробовать в адаптере запилить такой метод, сейчас обновлю ответ

Comment: я не пойму почему сюда maps.add(dataModel);после клика все равно добавляется null

Comment: @Сергей значит у тебя DataModel null

Comment: сейчас поставил по умолчанию поля в Datamodel равные const,  и теперь при добавлении значения добавляется просто тоже самое значение, получается что значение с alertDialoga не обработалось..совсем запутался что-то

Comment: @Сергей так ты же поставил const вот тоже самое и добавилось :)

Comment: ну я это понял, я имел в виду что не добавлись новые данные