# Обновление состояния ExpandableListView

Tags: android, listview

Есть кнопка при нажатии на которою в БД добавляется запись. Все записи с БД отображаются в `ExpandableListView`.

Обновляю, с помощью вызова метода `onResume()` при нажатии на кнопку, при этом в нем (в `onResume()` ) опять делается выборка с БД. Понимаю что так не практично и не оптимально делать. Как правильно сделать ?

Как сделать так, чтоб сразу после добавления БД, новая запись отображалась в листе ?

Comment: Добавление записи в БД и загрузка в список в разных активити происходит?

Comment: @Андроид Андроид, нет, добавление в БД и загрузка даных в список происходит в  одном фрагиенте !

Comment: Покажите код, постараюсь помочь

Comment: @Андроид Андроид, https://github.com/Vitaliy1995/MustTuDo.git.    код не сильно грмотный - мое первое приложение!!  Адаптер класс - TaskListAdapter,  клас фрагмента TaskFragment! Приму любую критику ))

Comment: А где надо посмотреть? в TaskFragment? upd ага вижу

Comment: По коду сложновато разобраться, слишком много, запустался=) Недавно у парня была примерно подобная проблема http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512341/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-listview-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/512352#512352, суть решения сводится к одному: Вам нужно создать список, объявить его глобально, инициализировать, и при инсерте в БД также добавлять этот элемент с помощью list.add(myItem)

Comment: После чего вызвать listView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged(); или же myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();. Тогда Ваш адаптер не будет перестраиваться заново, а просто дополнит новые/изменившиеся элементы. Плюс, Я вижу что Вы засовываете фрагмент в конструктор адаптера. По-хорошему, от этого надо избавиться

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, не могу понять, что я делаю не так.... применяю notifyDataSetChanged() в методах удаления и добавления записи, но ничего не происходит :((
Хотя сделал небольшую тренировку з одного активити и листа в который записи добавлялись - все работало !!

Comment: @АндроидАндроид. возможно глупый вопрос, но что имеется ввиду под "глобальный список" ?

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, спасибо за помощь!! 
Уже разобрался )))

Если вы оформите это как ответ - отмечу решенным )))

Comment: =) Чуть попозже оформлю

Answer (score 1):

После сохранения в БД получай из БД последнюю запись добавляй в список который в адаптере и вызывай метод адаптера notify();